# Let $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ and...

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, and $f(5) = -2$, $f'(0) = 3$, then find the value of $f'(5)$.

I thought a lot on this question. I tried to find out the function. I put $y=0$ to get $f(0)$ which comes out to be $1$. but then I could do no more.

Comment: Could you expand on how you got $f(0)=1$ please?

Comment: Put y=0 f(x)= f(x)f(0) so either f(x) is zero or f(0) is 1, but f(x) is not 0 because otherwise it would be a constant function and f(5) is -2. So f(0) is 1

Comment: Please check the source of the question. The problem appears to be invalid/incomplete. See below for more details.

Comment: But according to options given in this question the correct answer is -6.

Comment: Unfortunately also books and exam question on occasion do have typo's or mistakes in them. It appears that they wanted you to apply one of the methods below that produce the answer -6, but did not consider wether such a function can actually exist.

Comment: By replacing the "for all x,y" to a restricted range, the problem can be fixed to have a correct and proper solution.

Comment: It is a variation on an old and *wrong* question from a competitive exam in India. I have talked about it long back in my blog post as well as on MSE. See http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2010/08/two-problems-from-iit-jee.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have $f(0)=1$ or $f(0)=0$. If $f(0)=0$ , then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, which is not the case. Hence $f(0)=1$.

$f'(5)= \lim _{h \to 0}\frac{f(5+h)-f(5)}{h}=f(5) \lim _{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}=-2\lim _{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=-2 f'(0)=-6$

Comment: Awesome! A totally different approach than mine, yet both work :)

Comment: @5xum Mhm, these functional equations are quite fun with all the approaches you can take.

Comment: Well, since a function such as this one does not exist, one might as well say that $f'(5)=42$.

Answer (score 7):

There is a problem with this problem:  It cannot have a solution, because the hypotheses lead to a contradiction.

As others have noted,

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}{f(x+h)-f(x+0)\over h}=\lim_{h\to0}{f(x)f(h)-f(x)f(0)\over h}=f(x)\lim_{h\to0}{f(0+h)-f(0)\over h}=f(x)f'(0)$$

so $f$ is differentiable at all points, which requires $f$ to be *continuous* at all points.  But we also have $-2=f(5)=f(5+0)=f(5)f(0)=-2f(0)$, which implies $f(0)=1$.  And now, since $f(0)\gt0$ while $f(5)\lt0$, the Intermediate Value Theorem implies $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in(0,5)$.  But that implies $f(x+a)=f(x)f(a)=0$ for all $x$, and that's a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Take the equation $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$.

Now, on both sides, take the derivative with respect to $x$ (i.e., $y$ is a constant, and so is $f(y)$.

You get $$f'(x) f(y) = f'(x+y)$$

Now set $x=5, y=-5$ and you get$$f'(5)=\frac{f'(0)}{f(-5)}$$

So all you need to calculate $f'(5)$ is to know what $f(-5)$ is. To calculate that, set $x=5,y=-5$ in $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and you get $$f(0)=f(5)f(-5)$$

---

**Edit thanks to @BarryCipra**:

A shorter way to do it is to plug in $x=0, y=5$ and get$$f'(0)f(5)=f'(5)$$ immediatelly.

Comment: Why not let $x=0$, $y=5$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh yeah :)

Answer (score 3):

The question itself as presented now is invalid.

By taking $y=x$ we get $f(2 x) = f(x)^2$ from which it follows by induction that $f(n x) = f(x)^n$ for any integer $n$ and any value of $x$.

Taking $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $n=10$ we get $f(\frac{1}{2})^{10}=-2$ and hence $f(\frac{1}{2})$ needs to be a complex variable and hence the function $f(x)$ is complex. Note, that I did not use any derivatives yet.

This is not necessarily a problem in itself, but already looks suspicious for this type of problem.

We can also take the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0$ in $f(n \delta) = f(\delta)^n$ and since the question implies the existence of the derivatives locally the function $f(x)$ would have to be some exponential $f(x)=e^{\alpha x}$ for some complex constant $\alpha$. If we use the condition $f'(0)=3$ this gives $f(x)=e^{3x}$ but than the condition $f(5)=-2$ can not be satisfied.

The main issue here is the fact that the requirement $f(x+y)=f(x) f(y)$ is supposedly valid for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. If one would limit this range, for instance by restricting $x,y \in [-1,1] \cup [-4,6]$ the problem could be solved by creating some discontinuity in the function $f(x)$in a region not covered by the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple argument that the problem is invalid:

We have $f(2x)=f(x+x)=f(x)^2 \ge 0$ for all $x$. Hence $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$. But then $f(5) = -2$ is impossible !